# Performans of nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to ask a question about database queries. In case of query such like where clause of the query is coming from the another query. For example

```
select ? from ? where ? = select ? from ?
```

This is the simple example so it is easy to write this. But for the more complex case, i want to know what is the best way in case of performance. Join? seperate queries? nested or another?

Thank you for answers.

Best Regards.

Comment: depends on the RDBMS's optimizer, but a join is usually the prefered form.

Answer (score 1):

You should test it. These things depend a lot on the details of the query and of the indices it can use.

In my experience JOINs tend to be faster than nested queries in MySQL. In some cases MySQL isn't very smart and appears to run the subquery for every row produced by the outer query.

You can read more about these things in the official documentation:

Optimizing subqueries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-subqueries.html
Rewriting subqueries as joins: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

This is case dependent. In case you have a very less result in the inner query you should go for it. The flow works in the manner where in the inner query is executed first and the result set is being used in the outer query.
Meanwhile joins give you a Cartesian product which is again a heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

As Mitch and Joni stated, it depends. But generally a join will offer the best performance. You're trying to avoid running the nested query for each row of the outer query. A good query optimizer may do this for you anyway, by interpreting what you're trying to do and essentially "fixing" your mistake. But with the vast majority of queries, you should be writing it as a join in the first place. That way you're being explicit about what you're trying to do and you're fully understanding yourself what is being done, and what the most efficient way to do the work is.

Answer (score 0):

I EXPECT the joins to be quicker, mainly because you have an equivalence and an explicit JOIN. Still use explain to see the differences in how the SQl engine will interpret them.
I would not expect these to be so different, where you can get real, large performance gains in using joins instead of subqueries is when you use correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Since almost everyone is saying that joins will give the optimal performance I just logged in to say the exact opposite experience I had.

So some days back I was writing a query for 3-4 tables which had huge amount of data. I wrote a big sql query with joins and it was taking around 2-3 hours to execute it. Then I restructured it, created a nested select query, put as many where constraints as I can inside the nested one & made it as stricter as possible and then the performance improved by >90%, it now takes less than 4 mins to run.

This is just my experience and may be theoretically joins are better. I just felt to share my experience. Its better to try out different things, getting additional knowledge about the tables, it's indexes etc would help a lot.

**Update:**

And I just found out what I did is actually suggested in this optimization reference page of MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-subqueries.html

Pasting it here for quick reference:

> **Replace a join with a subquery. For example, try this:**
>
> SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.column1 IN (   SELECT column1
>   FROM t2);
>
> Instead of this:
>
> SELECT DISTINCT t1.column1 FROM t1, t2   WHERE t1.column1 =
>   t2.column1;
>
> **Move clauses from outside to inside the subquery.** For example, use
>   this query:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1   WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s1 FROM t1 UNION ALL SELECT s1
>   FROM t2); Instead of this query:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1   WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s1 FROM t1) OR s1 IN (SELECT s1
>   FROM t2); For another example, use this query:
>
> SELECT (SELECT column1 + 5 FROM t1) FROM t2; Instead of this query:
>
> SELECT (SELECT column1 FROM t1) + 5 FROM t2;